# What is the standard way to hide a login button?

Tags: 9

I have a website to which no user besides me should login.

What is the standard way to hide a login button?

Of course, one can use CSS or JavaScript or customize a Twig file but is there a standard or recommended way?

I didn't find a login block to remove in `structure/blocks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Admin -> Configuration -> People and for 'who can register accounts' choose 'administrators only'.

Comment: Sadly that does not hide the button... At least not in Drupal 9.4.6 with Olivero.

Comment: In that case, you can just remove the login block.

Comment: Thank you, please read my answer.

Comment: Hiding the button doesn't hide the route, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-users/hide-user-login) some instruction to hide the login page.
For the login button, if you mean the one in the menù, you may disable at `/admin/structure/menu/link/user.logout/edit`

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove the "User account menu" block.

I figure that in Drupal 9.4.6 the login block was renamed from "Login" to "User account menu" or that the "User account menu" block now covers logging in as well.

It is recommended however to do what Jaypan suggested in his answer as well (disabling the ability of anonymous users to create account).